# Serverless deployment errorL Environment variable iamRoleStatements must contain string

Tags: node.js, serverless-framework, serverless

I am trying to locally run `serverless deploy` but getting this error:

```
  Serverless Error ---------------------------------------
  Environment variable iamRoleStatements must contain string
```

Below is the relevant part from my `serverless.yml`

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs10.x
  stage: prod
  region: us-east-1
  environment:
    tableName: profiles
    iamRoleStatements:
      - Effect: Allow
        Action:
          - dynamodb:DescribeTable
          - dynamodb:Query
          - dynamodb:Scan
          - dynamodb:GetItem
          - dynamodb:PutItem
          - dynamodb:UpdateItem
          - dynamodb:DeleteItem
        Resource: 'arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:*:*'
```

Below is my environment information:

```
Your Environment Information ---------------------------
 Operating System:          darwin
 Node Version:              12.16.1
 Framework Version:         1.64.0
 Plugin Version:            3.4.0
 SDK Version:               2.3.0
 Components Core Version:   1.1.2
 Components CLI Version:    1.4.0
```

Any idea where I might be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your iam roles seem to be configured correctly.

Double check your indentation on the roles are correct, at first I would say it's probably missing one space at least comparing the environment definitions

```
  environment:
    tableName: profiles

  iamRoleStatements:
   - Effect: Allow
```

Comment: it was an indentation issue. Thanks!